# PHP mail with postfix delivery status

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-16.04, postfix-mta

I have an ubuntu 16.04 server with postfiy.
I have this PHP code:

```
$to = emailto@address.com
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: emailfrom@address.com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Is there a way to check if my email was delivered successfully?

Answer (score 0):

```
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($send){
    echo 'send';
}else{
    echo 'some error';
}
```

something like that ?